# Setting data-ng-model in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to set an data-ng-model variable from a controller, but i get this error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined`

here is the html : `<input id="1" data-ng-model="name" type="text">`
and the controller : `$scope.name="5656";`

this changes the text of the input, but not the `data-ng-model="name"` variable (whcich is what i need)

```
$('#1').val("hello");
```

update- controller defenition:

```
editApp.controller('EditController', function ($scope,$http, $routeParams, customersService,$location) {
...
});
```

Comment: Can you show your controller definition? You could probably ensure if $scope in injected into the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the best thing I can do to help!

http://jsfiddle.net/vcy80edg/

```
var editApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function EditController($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Hey friend!';
}
```